# NodeJS express basicAuth - how to pass username to the route function?

Tags: node.js, express, basic-authentication

I've got a working node app where I need to connect to different DBs based on what user is connecting to the app via basicAuth.

Here's a sample:

```
// Authenticating function
var sgAuth = express.basicAuth(function(user, pass, callback){
  if(config.credentials.clients[user] === undefined) {
    callback(null, false);
  } else {
    callback(null, config.credentials.clients[user].password == pass);
  }
});

// This function needs to know what user has authenticated
function putEvents(req, res) {
    //How do I know what user authenticated in this request?
    var authUser = ???;
    var table = getUserTable(authUser);
    ...
}
app.post('/put', sgAuth, putEvents);
```

Storing username in sgAuth to some var surely won't work, because there can be many incoming connections from different users, so you can't guarantee that its the same user, right? Can this info be retrieved from the request header somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`basicAuth()` middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/basicAuth.html) will set `req.user` and `req.remoteUser` once authorized.

Though, note that the 2nd argument to the callback is expected to be the `user`, not simply an `authorized` boolean. But, it can be any *truthy* value you desire, including the `user` name.

```
callback(null, config.credentials.clients[user].password == pass ? user : null);
```

After that, you should be able to retrieve it with:

```
var authUser = req.user;
```

Comment: Doh, I literally just noticed that I should be returning username! :) `callback(null, config.credentials.clients[user].password == pass ? user : false)`

Comment: May I ask what is the purpose of utils.pause?

Comment: @KatyaS [It seems to be](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/2.12.0/lib/utils.js#L239-L266) a backward-compatible [`readable.pause()`](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/2.12.0/lib/utils.js#L239-L257), which prevents the `req` from streaming `data` (any body content) while waiting on the `callback`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that: basicAuth is deprecated

Here the code:

```
app.use(express.basicAuth(function(user, pass, callback){
  if(config.credentials.clients[user] === undefined) {
    callback('user not found!!!');
  } else {
    if(config.credentials.clients[user].password === pass) {
       callback(null, config.credentials.clients[user]);
    } else {
       callback('wrong pass!!!');
    }
  }
});

app.post('/put', function putEvents(req, res) {
   console.log(req.user.name) 
   res.end();
});
```

Comment: Deprecated? Hmm, will need to investigate. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @KatyaS It's deprecated, but apparently isn't planned to be removed. [Source](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/2.12.0/lib/middleware/basicAuth.js#L18-L20). Though, the author still recommends using [`basic-auth`](https://npmjs.org/package/basic-auth).